# Verify if $e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x^2 \sin(x)$ is a little-o of $x^{2}$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ using limit

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I have to verify if $e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x \sin(x)$ is a little-o of $x^{2}$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ using limit, i.e. calculating the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x^2 \sin(x)}{x^{2}} $$

and if the result is $0$, then the answer is "yes".

My first question is: is it acceptable that $x \to 0^{+}$? I mean: I always did exercises with limit from left and right. Is the little-o notation defined also with limit only from right side or left side?

My second question is: ho can I calculate the limit?

Thanks

EDIT

My attempt of solution using L'Hopital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x^2 \sin(x)}{x^{2}} \\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}}}{x^{2}}+\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{x^{2}\sin(x)}{x^{2}}\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^{3}}-\sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}})}{\frac{d}{dx}x^{2}} + \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\sin(x)\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{x^{2}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{(1-x^{4})^{3}}}+3e^{x^{3}}\right)}{2x} + 0\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{(1-x^{4})^{3}}}+3e^{x^{3}}\right)\\
\frac{0}{2}\left(\frac{0}{1}+3\right)=
0
$$

Is it OK?

EDIT #2

My attempt of solution following the hint by Claude Leibovici

$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x^2 \sin(x)}{x^{2}} \\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{1+x^{3}-(1-x^{4})+x^{2}x}{x^{2}}\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1+x^3-1+x^4+x^3}{x^2}\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x^4+2x^3}{x^2}\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\cancel{x^{2}}(x^{2}+2x)}{\cancel{x^{2}}}\\
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x^2+2x = 0 
$$

Is it OK?

Comment: Regarding the first question, it's fine to use one-sided limits. When we say $f(x)=o(g(x))$ there's an implicit "as $x$ approaches $c$" and you can modify this to "as $x$ approaches $c$ from above / below."

Comment: One solution is to use Taylor series. Another solution is to use L'Hopital's rule twice.

Comment: @bjorn93 OK. Thank you.

Comment: @Ameji B. I added my attempt of solution using L'Hopital's rule. Thanks for the hint. But I used it only one time. Where I have to use it for the second time?

Comment: @BarryCipra. Stupid typo ! Thanks for pointing. It is so hard for me to type in comments.

Comment: You can use equivalents too : $e^{x^3}\sim 1+x^3$, $\sqrt[4]{1-x^4}\sim 1-\frac {x^4}4$, $\sin(x)\sim x$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for the hint. I used it and added my attempt of solution. But I used $1-x^4$. I don't understand why I have to use $1-\frac{x^4}{4}$.

Comment: @rookie_of_math. Binomial expansion

Comment: In both proofs there are some small mistakes. In the first, you take that derivative of the fourth root incorrectly, there should be an extra factor of -1/4 i think. For the second proof, as Claude said, the Taylor expansion of the fourth root is 1 - x^4/4.

Comment: @Ameji B. I have calculated the derivate of $e^{x^3}-\sqrt[4]{1-x^4}$ as follows: $$\require{cancel}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^3}-\sqrt[4]{1-x^4})=\\e^{x^3}\frac{d}{dx}x^3-\frac{1}{4}(1-x^4)^{\frac{1}{4}-1}\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^4)=\\3x^2 e^{x^3}-\frac{1}{\cancel{4}}(1-x^4)^{-\frac{3}{4}}(-\cancel {4}x^3)=\\3x^2e^{x^3}+\frac{x^3}{\sqrt[4]{(1-x^4)^3}}=\\x^2\left(3e^{x^3}+\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{(1-x^4)^3}}\right)$$ What's wrong? About $1-\frac{x^4}{4}$: why can't I use $1-x^4$? As for my calculation $\sqrt[4]{1-x^4} \sim 1-x^4$ when $x \to 0^{+}$: what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We can simply using asymptotics relations:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x^2 \sin(x)}{x^{2}}\,\,=\,\,\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left(e^{x^{3}} - 1\right)+\left(1-\sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}}\right) + x^2 \sin(x)}{x^{2}}\,\,\sim\,\,\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^4+x^3}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{o(x^2)}{x^2}=0$$

So, $e^{x^{3}} - \sqrt[4]{1-x^{4}} + x^2 \sin(x) = o(x^2)$ as you wanted to show.